# Magnetic field intensity in centre of square shaped wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I have 1m($l$) long wire which is bent into square. Through it flows 10A($I$) strong current. I have to calculate magnetic field intensity in centre of square.

[image]

Assuming my trig calculations are correct, I input 0.128 as $l$ into this formula

$$H = \frac{I}{2R}$$

and get 39 A/m, while answer in book is 35.8 A/m.
Is the error in my trigonometry or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is certainly a problem with your trigonometry (why would the yellow distance be different to the green?), but I think also with the equation you are using. Try searching for the Biot-Savart law.

Comment: Yeah I rounded it improperly, but anyways error in result shouldn't be that big. However, formula I am using is Bio-Savart law for, I quote and translate my book "Intensity in circle current centre" (hope I translated somewhat understandably)

Comment: But your current loop is not a circle. A square and a circle have different geometries, and different magnetic fields at their centers.

Comment: This is a homework question, so I am certainly not going to just provide the answer. I have, however, pointed out the problem, which is that OP needs to use the appropriate formula for the situation (a square loop instead of a circle).

Comment: No one is asking you to provide a solution to the homework problem

Comment: @AaronStevens, how do you interpret Thomas Fritsch's comment?

Comment: It's an auto-generated comment from a review queue. Thomas and at least one other user thinks your answer reads more like a comment. I must say I agree as well.